# GLSL - computing normals of fragments

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, terrain

I'm trying to create a program that displays a globe with terrain, and does all Lat/Long/Alt to XYZ (ECEF) on the GPU.

I've already written a working vertex shader that translates XYZ that represents Longitude, Latitude and Altitude (respectively) to their correct XYZ (using ECEF).

What I can't get done right is the lighting.

I've managed to light each vertex correctly using directional lights as long as there is no terrain data. Terrain data is not lighted correctly and I can't get different slopes to have correct shades.

This is the vertex shader I'm using:

```
const float a = 6378137.0;
const float f = 0.003352810664747480719845528618;

varying vec3 Normal;
varying vec3 ecPos;

vec3 LatLonAltToEcef(in vec3 latLonAlt)
{
    vec3 v = latLonAlt;

    float cosLat = cos(radians(v.y));
    float sinLat = sin(radians(v.y));
    float nfs = (1.0 - f) * (1.0 - f);

    float C = 1.0 / (sqrt(cosLat * cosLat + nfs * sinLat * sinLat));
    float S = nfs * C;

    float lon = radians(v.x);
    float h = v.z;

    v.x = (a * C + h) * cosLat * cos(lon) / a;
    v.y = (a * C + h) * cosLat * sin(lon) / a;
    v.z = (a * S + h) * sinLat / a;

    return v;
}

vec4 LatLonAltToEcef(in vec4 latLonAlt)
{
    vec3 ecef = LatLonAltToEcef(latLonAlt.xyz);
    return vec4(ecef.x, ecef.y, ecef.z, latLonAlt.w);
}

void main(void)
{
    vec4 v = LatLonAltToEcef(gl_Vertex); //x=lon, y=lat, z=alt
    ecPos = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * v);

    Normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * v.xyz);
    vec4 lightPos = LatLonAltToEcef(gl_LightSource[0].position);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * lightPos.xyz);
    float NdotL = max(dot(Normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse;

    gl_FrontColor =  NdotL * diffuse;
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * v;
}
```

In order to draw a globe grid this is what needs to be done:

```
for (float lat = -90; lat < 90; lat += 5)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (float lon = -180; lon < 180; lon += 5)
        glVertex3f(lon, lat, 0);
    glEnd();
}

for (float lon = -180; lat < 180; lon += 5)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (float lat = -90; lon < 90; lon += 5)
        glVertex3f(lon, lat, 0);
    glEnd();
}
```

Can any one please direct me how to shade the terrain correctly?

Answer (score 5):

I feel that you need to study more computer graphics, as there seem to be some gaps in your basic knowledge about computer rendered geometry.

Anyway:

Getting the normal (surface direction) at any point usually require looking at the surroundings, if you don't have slope information from the beginning.

Secondly, you probably want to draw triangles, not lines.

Triangles have a surface. Surfaces has normals. Normals are vectors, that can have angles towards other vectors. Light direction is a vector. The dot product is your friend. :)

So, having a set of triangles connecting your vertices will help you in getting somewhere.

Also, avoid computing stuff in a shader that can be computed once and for all before any rendering.

Comment: +1 for "avoid computing stuff in a shader that can be computed once and for all before any rendering"

Comment: I know that. The lines was just an example for usage of the shader I wrote. I had another model over it that represented terrain that was built using triangles aligned in a grid (simple height map model). That model was not lit correctly, thus my question - as I didn't find a way to compute the correct normal for each fragment or pixel in the shaders...

Comment: "avoid computing stuff in a shader that can be computed once and for all before any rendering" - I'm planning on dynamically changing terrain (replacing tiles). Is using display lists count as not re-computing?

Comment: @Itai: Display lists are ok, but they are not recommended anymore, due to inherent inefficiencies. But storing "only geometry" in them is ok (try to avoid doing anything else). Most modern OpenGL code uses Vertex Buffer Objects instead. Also, for tiling, there are many good articles describing how to do efficient tiled level-of-detail terrain available in books and on the internet.

Comment: @Itai: W.r.t. your first comment. You should pre-compute the normal at each vertex before rendering. Then you can use that normal in your shader, either directly, to do per-vertex lighting, or indirectly, by interpolating it across a triangle, to do per-fragment lighting. For even better lighting, you might want to use a normal map instead, but that's advanced graphics. :) In order to see if your normals are correct, learn to interpret RGB as XYZ and/or make a small routine that draws the normals in your model as lines. (So, pre-compute your normals and verity before yo uuse them for lighing)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here :

```
Normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * v.xyz);
```

By luck, you found a rare case where using the position of the vertex also gives you the normal : the sphere ( but since Earth is not a sphere, your lighting isn't 100% correct though)

When you add mountains, this isn't true anymore. Normals are perpendicular to the ground, so on a mountain, it's bent.

You need a line like this :

```
Normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal.xyz);
```

gl_Normal is given by calls to glNormal3f, just before glVertex3f. But you don't say how you give terrain data so you'll have to find parameters to glNormal3f yourself. They must be expressed in model space (i.e. NOT lon/lat, but XYZ relative to the center of the earth, in a *cartesian* space. Again : a cartesian space.)

Comment: I see. However what I'm trying to achieve is to avoid having to convert Lat/Long to XYZ in code. Suppose I provide my geometry as a triangle strip (or triangles, for that matter) - The shader converts each vertex from Lat/Long/Alt to XYZ. I know (and perhaps mistaken) that OpenGL automatically computes the normals of triangles (please correct me if I'm wrong). How can I be given the vertices of each triangles in a shader so I can compute its normal and how can I pass the computed normal on to compute lighting?

Comment: @Itai: OpenGL will do nothing automatically. Normals are just another vertex attribute you must supply. Also you should precompute Lat/Lon into XYZ: Doing it in the shader forces the GPU to perform a task again and again for each frame, which could have been done once and for all. Normals could be calculated in a very convoluted wayy using the fragment shader using the partial derivative functions http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/dFdx.xml however its much easier and simpler to calculate them offline once.

Comment: "How can I be given the vertices of each triangles in a shader" -> In a geometry shader; but this is a bit overkill IMHO. I really suggest you learn how to pass normals, and later, if performance is a problem, consider computing them on the fly.

Comment: It's mich easier to transform normals (in a shader), than to derive them from the vertex positions.

Comment: @datenwolf : Well yeah, that's pretty much what I mean, sorry I this wasn't clear...